# Entity Framework Updating 100K Records

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF6 with SQLCE database with few tables which have more than 200K records each.  I am trying to update records in one of those tables but unfortunately, the updating process is very slow using the bellow methods:

```
var original = db.Users.Find(updatedUser.UserId);

if (original != null)
{
    original.BusinessEntityId = updatedUser.BusinessEntityId;
    original.Email = updatedUser.Email;
    original.EmployeeId = updatedUser.EmployeeId;
    original.Forename = updatedUser.Forename;
    original.Surname = updatedUser.Surname;
    original.Telephone = updatedUser.Telephone;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The second method I tried is to actually get all records from database, then do the comparison in memory and after loop through resulted List in order to update the database:

```
  foreach (var _data in comparedList)
  {
      using (var db = new MyContext())
      {
          db.Users.Attach(data);
          var entry = context.Entry(data);
          entry.Property(p => p.Forename).IsModified = true;
          context.SaveChanges();
      }
  }
```

Any idea about efficient way of updating records using EF?

## EDIT

I've used also techniques presented in the [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework) they eventually lead to the "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).” errors.

Comment: Don't call `SaveChanges()` until you are done updating all the records.

Comment: use a stored procedure which accepts a userid as parameter.  It is much faster and use the database engine for mass update.

Comment: I suggest to alter your question to give a full reproduction of the problem. Then ping me and I will reopen the post.

Answer (score 3):

EF is not designed for mass updates - it is designed for queries and transactional updates (a few records at a time).

If you need to mass-update data then either write a SQL statement that will do all of the updates or use an ETL tool like SSIS.

Comment: I am aware of it, however I am looking the fastest way doing it using EF.